# join multiple queries result in to seperate columns

Tags: sql-server

hello everyone i have 3 queries it gives when i used union All its give me 3 rows i want to convert 3 rows into columns how can i do that please help me

here is my query

```
( select count(*) As TotalCount from Detail_User 
where userkey = 172 ) 
--union
( select count(*) As ICount1 from Detail_User 
where Parent_Name = 'A' and userkey = 172 )
--union
( select count(*) As ICount2 from Detail_User 
where Parent_Name = 'B' and userkey = 172 )
```

its give me some thing like this

```
TotalCount
2
3
5
```

i want something like this

```
TotalCount ICount1 ICount2
2          3       5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do a `UNION`, use a `CASE WHEN` in your `SELECT` like this

```
select
count(*) As TotalCount,
SUM(CASE WHEN Parent_Name = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ICount1 ,
SUM(CASE WHEN Parent_Name = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ICount2 
from Detail_User 
where userkey = 172
```